# Capturing OpenMP exceptions with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter

Tags: c++, windows, openmp

I have an exception handler set up using `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`, which works fine. However, if I throw an exception from within OpenMP code, I get the standard "the application crashed" window and the handler is not called -- however, I can attach a debugger just fine and see that the call stack is ending with _CxxThrowException and continues into KernelBase.dll!RaiseException. I know that an OpenMP program which throws exceptions inside the parallel regions is wrong, but I'd still like to get a crash dump. How can I get my exception handler get called in this case?

Should be possible, especially as the debugger manges to get an "Unhandled exception" window, when attached to the application after the crash (i.e. I can get a nice stack trace and stuff.) This is on Windows 7 with VC++ 2010.

(Eventually, each thread actually calls my exception handler. If it crashes, and I select 'Debug', and then continue on each unhandled exception, the handler eventually gets called and it also manages to write out a meaningful minidump. Wtf?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  Going out on a limb, I'll wager that the OpenMP concurrency runtime doesn't honor the SetUnhandledExceptionFilter (which will work for "standard" threads), and isn't integrated into this feature of Structured Exception Handling.

Note this warning from the [MSDN page on Exception Handling in the Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997692.aspx#Y839)

`To prevent abnormal termination of your application, make sure that your code handles exceptions when it calls into the runtime. Also handle exceptions when you call into external code that uses the Concurrency Runtime, for example, a third-party library.`

Perhaps you can try wrapping your OpenMP stuff in the style of exception handling outlined above, and then see if you can re-package and throw it (outside of OpenMP context) to get caught by the filter?